# Why are the rightmost borders of tables in MS word getting misaligned and how to stop that from happening?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

I added a table to MS Word and I noticed that the rightmost borders of individual rows would sometimes get misaligned as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

One minute they are fine and then the next I notice a bunch of them (ones I haven't even touched!) are misaligned. What can cause that to happen and how to prevent it from happening? Does it have something to do with the fact that some rows were inserted using the Right Click->Insert Rows.. function?

This is on a Windows 10 running in a VM.

Comment: How did you add the table? was it imported from Excel or some other software?

Comment: Why are you running in a virtual machine? What is your base platform? Mac? Are you or others accessing this document from other versions of Microsoft Word?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad No importing. Just Insert->Table

Comment: @RichMichaels I'm running it on a VM because my host OS is Linux and Microsoft is not kind enough to offer Office apps for that platform. They say the web apps are enough completely ignoring the fact that they're pretty much unusable if you need to do anything beyond just text with headers.

Comment: What version of Office are you running and do others edit this file as well as yourself?